# got error 1314 when doing SetTokenInformation

Tags: winapi

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Userenv.h>
#include <Wtsapi32.h>
int main() {
    DWORD err;
    err=GetLastError();
    printf( "err001:%d\n",err);
    HANDLE hTokenThis = NULL;
    HANDLE hTokenDup = NULL;
    HANDLE hThisProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    OpenProcessToken(hThisProcess, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hTokenThis);
    err=GetLastError();
    printf( "err002:%d\n",err);
    DuplicateTokenEx(hTokenThis, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hTokenDup);
    err=GetLastError();
    printf( "err003:%d\n",err);
    DWORD dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, hTokenDup);
    //DWORD dwSessionId = 1;
    SetTokenInformation(hTokenDup, TokenSessionId, &dwSessionId, sizeof(DWORD));
    err=GetLastError();
    printf( "err004:%d\n",err);
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.lpDesktop = "WinSta0\\Default";
    LPVOID pEnv = NULL;
    DWORD dwCreationFlag = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
    CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv, hTokenDup, FALSE);
    err=GetLastError();
    printf( "err005:%d\n",err);
    CreateProcessAsUser(
            hTokenDup,
            NULL,
            (char *)"notepad",
            NULL,
            NULL,
            FALSE,
            dwCreationFlag,
            pEnv,
            NULL,
            &si,
            &pi);
    printf("here we go\n");
    err=GetLastError();
    printf( "err006:%d\n",err);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:
gcc -o session.exe session.c  c://Windows/System32/kernel32.dll  c://Window
s/System32/wtsapi32.dll  -lUserenv

Running Result:

```
session.exe
err001:126
err002:126
err003:126
err004:1314
err005:203
here we go
err006:87
```

gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC) from mingw.

btw, just ignore the error 126.

My question is :
Why got error 1314?

I want to start a program in the interactive desktop from service by using CreateProcessAsUser without knowing the logon user and password.

Answer (score 2):

Error `1314` is "A required privilege is not held by the client".

From the `WTSQueryUserToken()` docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840.aspx):

> To call this function successfully, the calling application must be running within the context of the LocalSystem account and have the SE_TCB_NAME privilege

Also your call to `WTSQueryUserToken()` should look like:

```
WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, &hTokenDup);
```

And you'll need appropriate privileges for `SetTokenInformation()` enabled as well.

Bottom line is that you're trying to do something that Windows reserves for highly privileged processes, so you'll need to make sure your process is configured to run appropriately (maybe as a service that talks to a regular non-privileged process for user interaction).

Comment: Actually even I run this program directly in the cmd, it still shows error 1314.

Comment: I mean, I got error 1314 as well even I run it on the cmd.exe which started on the current active logon desktop. I am confused about this privilege.

Comment: If you launch from a cmd window, the your process will be running under the account of that cmd window (which will be the logged on user (unless you're doing something special like starting the cmd with "runas"). It's almost certainly not running under the LocalSystem account. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2004/11/27/271063.aspx for a way to run cmd under LocalSystem (though I wouldn't be too surprised if this doesn't work on recent versions of Windows). You also might need to explicitly enable the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619.aspx

Comment: Keith Brown's book, "Programming Windows Security" (http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Security-Keith-Brown/dp/0201604426), has great coverage on all this stuff. However it's pretty old, so I'm not sure whether it would have too many gaps due to security changes MS has made over the past decade. Since you can get a used/remaindered one for the cost of shipping, I'd still recommend it.

Comment: Why do I have to run it under the LocalSystem account? I just want to be able to start certain program with CreateProcessAsUser() under the logged on user's environment, which should be the session and station of the interactive desktop.

Comment: @Chen: I'm just letting you know what the docs say. Are you creating the process from another user account and another session?

Comment: I will create the process from a service(creating from service is the next stage). But for now, what I want is: Write a small program as the topic I posted, which will start the "notepad" with CreateProcessAsUser(). I will run this small program in current desktop - by double clicking it or by issuing  it in the cmd.exe.

Comment: Actually I think I don't need to post so many codes - since I run this program in the current desktop, so I think I can use the token of current process to pass to createprocessasuser(). So DuplicateTokenEx(), etc. are useless for now.